# Simpler way to check for collision?

Tags: c#, winforms, if-statement

I'm working on an assignment for uni where I have to create a Breakout game in Visual Studio 2010 using C# Win Forms. At the moment, I am concentrating on there being only one brick to be destroyed so I have the mechanics down before expanding on it.

To clarify about my current program: I am using a picture box as a Graphics object and a timer to create the animation effect. The ball can skip, at each frame, between 1 and 10 pixels — this is part of creating a random starting vector for the ball.

This works fine until it comes to checking if the ball has 'hit' the brick I have drawn. What I have is an if statement that checks if the ball is at any of the coordinates on the picture box that corresponds to the outline of the brick. I know that the logic is fine because it works some of the time. However, because of the variation in the 'jumping' of the ball's position, I need to add a buffer area of +/- 5 pixels to my if statement.

This is where the problem arises, because my `if` statement (two, really) is *really* complicated as it is:

```
// Checks if ball hits left side or top of brick
if (((x >= brickX) && (x <= (brickX + 50)) && (y == brickY)) ||
    ((y >= brickY) && (y <= (brickY + 20)) && (x == brickX)))
{
    brickHit = true;
}
// Check if ball hits right side or bottom of brick
else if ((((x >= brickX) && (x <= brickX + 50)) && (y == (brickY + 20))) ||
    (((y >= brickY) && (y <= brickY + 20)) && (x == brickX + 50)))
{
    brickHit = true;
}
```

For clarification: x and y are the coordinates of the ball and brickX and brickY are the coordinates of the top-left corner of the rectangle brick (which is 50 pixels wide, 10 pixels high).

**Is there any way to simplify the above if statements?** If I can make them simpler, I know it'll be much easier to add in the 'buffer' (which only needs to be 5 pixels either side of the brick's outline' to allow for the ball's change in position).

*If further clarification is needed, please ask — I'm writing this question at 5:12am so I know I might be a little unclear.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
brickHit = new Rectangle(brickX,brickY,50,20).Contains(x,y);
```

Adding a buffer:

```
int buffer = 5;
brickHit = new Rectangle(brickX,brickY,50,20).Inflate(buffer,buffer).Contains(x,y);
```

The Rectagle class can come in handy sometimes.

Comment: Oooh, nice. Question, though: Does that return a true/false value?

Comment: @Saladin @Computer Not to be nitpicky here, but 1. Inflate returns void, you cannot call .Contains on it. You need to create the rectangle, do the Inflate as a separate call and then call contains on it, also 2. a heads up on Inflate, it only moves the increases the size of the brick down and to the right, if you need the +5 buffer on the left and top you will need to offset the rectangle first, if you just need the space on the left, right and bottom then Offset(-5, 0) and then Inflate(10, 5)

Answer (score 5):

One way you could possible simplify this (and I may be misunderstanding your spec), but you can make a Rectangle out of the bounds of the brick and check the Contains for your x,y point.

```
Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(brickX, brickY, 50, 20);
rec.Offset(-5, -5);
rec.Inflate(10, 10);
if (rec.Contains(new Point(x,y))
{
    brickHit = true;
}
```

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense. But, when you say to make a rectangle out of the bounds of the picture box, do you mean that the brick would be the same size as the picture box?

Comment: It would if you do just the Box.Bounds (Bounds returns a rectangle). If you want you can Inflate it to add the +5 pixels you are looking for (Inflate will add the amount to the rectangle). In your case if you need a +5 buffer all around then you would need to "move" the rectangles location (Offset(-5, -5)) and then Inflate(10, 10). (You should double check the math as it is late, but I think that is what you are looking for). Contains returns a bool indicating that the specified Point is contained in the rectangle.

Comment: I updated the code in my answer to Offset and Inflate the rectangle. This should now give you a rectangle that is +5 bigger on all sides.

Comment: @Saladin just re-reading. I was getting the bounds of the picture box because I thought that was the brick. I misunderstood you. If the picture box is not the brick then you need to make the Rectangle with your brickX and brickY and the dimensions you described.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
var rect1 = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(pictureBox1.Location,
pictureBox1.Size);
var rect2 = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(pictureBox2.Location, 
pictureBox2.Size);

if (rect1.IntersectsWith(rect2))
{
  //code when collided
}
```